# How can I manipulate DOM in a closure to write values in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, closures

I want to upload multiple files via input.

These files are csv and contain GPS coordinates and the name of the file contains date and time. So i think, that i need a closure to make the information available. But how can i use the values outside the function?

I tried to create a tablehead @ first outside the closure. In the closure, which is in a loop, i want to create a table-row for the Parameters, but i'm getting only one row.

The second idea was to get the innerhtml of an output-element and add the new Parameters every round. This works but isnt a good solution, because i have to split the string again.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
function dateiAusgewaehlt(evt) {

document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "";

//============================ init tablehead===================================================================

var tabellenkopf = ['Jahr', 'Monat', 'Tag', 'Stunde', 'Minute', 'Sekunde', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'];
var table = document.createElement("table");
output = document.getElementById("list");
output.appendChild(table);
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
table.appendChild(thead);
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
thead.appendChild(tr);

for (var i=0;i<tabellenkopf.length;i++)
{
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    tr.appendChild(th);
    th.id = "th"+i;
}

for (var i=0;i<tabellenkopf.length;i++)
{
    var thtext = document.createTextNode(tabellenkopf[i]);
    document.getElementById("th"+i).appendChild(thtext);
    thtext.id = "thtext"+i;
}
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tbody);


//==========================================================================

var files = evt.target.files;   //Speicherung der Fileliste
var year;
var month;
var day;
var hour;
var minute;
var second;


for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var dateiname;
    var zeit;
    var sectmp;
    var teilstring;
    var inhalt;

    var reader = new FileReader();



    reader.onload = (function(f) {
        return function(e) {

            dateiname = encodeURI(f.name);
            dateiname = dateiname.split("%20");
            zeit = dateiname[2];
            zeit = zeit.split("_");
            year = zeit[0];
            month = zeit[1];
            day = zeit[2];
            hour = zeit[3];
            minute = zeit[4];
            sectmp = zeit[5];
            sectmp = sectmp.split(".");
            second = sectmp[0];

            inhalt = e.target.result;
            teilstring = inhalt.split(",");
            latitude = teilstring[29].substring(0,2) + "." + teilstring[29].substring(2,teilstring[29].length);
            longitude = teilstring[32].substring(0,2) + "." + teilstring[32].substring(2,teilstring[32].length);
```

//===================that is not working==============

```
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        var td0 = document.createElement("td");
        tr.appendChild(td0);
        var td0text = document.createTextNode(year);
        td0.appendChild(td0text);
```

//===============that is working========

```
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = document.getElementById
        ("list").innerHTML + "<br />"+ year +"."+ month +"."+ day +" "
        + hour +":"+ minute +":"+ second + " Position: " + " LAT: " +
        latitude + " LONG: " + longitude;
        };

    })(file);
    reader.readAsText(file);
    }

};

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', dateiAusgewaehlt, false);
```

Comment: is "year" returing a String or at least something besides "null" or "undefined"?

Comment: year is "2015". So if i upload 5 files it should Looks like:

Jahr-2015,2015,2015,2015,2015
but it creates only 1 row
Jahr-2015

Comment: The "not working" code is actually working (FIrefox 40) so I'm guessing the problem is in some part of the loop, since it creates only one row

Comment: i use IE. Closures break my head. If i set a alert @ the position of the tablecreation the number of alerts = number of files... but the dommanipulation will execute only 1 time. Is it possible to declare an globalarray and .push the new values?

Comment: Not trying to be a "sheep" but the IE MIGHT be the problem. Yes, it's possible to do so (and I understand you probably have to make this work on Internet Explorer)

Comment: IE is the only option, because it is the companystandard.

Comment: just as I suspected hehe. Sorry, I can't seem to help anymore at the moment. Upvoting your question, however.